# Login user with SMS in react native like in BHIM UPI app

Tags: react-native, authentication, sms, upi

I am building an app in React-Native. I want to signup user with his phone using. For example, when I login with BHIM UPI app, it doesn't ask for any permissions. It can read information about my carrier and send a message from my phone to its back-end API. Once it receives the message from my number, it creates an account against my number. This behavior is same on android and iPhone. I want to do the same. Does any know how I can do that?

One other way is to create an API on my back-end which can receive a number (customer's number) and then from the back-end I can send an OTP to that number (customer's number) and then customer can enter OTP in the app to confirm the identity. However, there is a problem with this strategy; anyone can send (unlimited) requests to this API which will increase my billing amount so it's not financially safe.